# Keras Cnn Model wont improve Accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to implement a Cnn using Keras on a Sklearn dataset for handwritten digits recognition (load_digits). I have got the model to run but it is not improving the accuracy for each 'epochs' cycle, Im guessing its because my labels are incorrect, I have tried encoding my Y values with use of 'to_categorical' but it displays the following error:

```
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4979 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py:173 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 10))
```

When i run my code without trying to encode the Y values it seems to go through the Cnn Model however it isn't accurate and it doesn't increase, this is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

#from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical

X,y = datasets.load_digits(return_X_y = True)
X = X/16
#X = X.reshape(1797,8,8,1)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y)

train_x = train_x.reshape(1347,8,8,1)
#test_x = test_x.reshape()

#train_y = to_categorical(train_y, num_classes = 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=( 8, 8, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=6, validation_split=0.3)

print(train_x[0])
```

And this gives me the following output:

```
Epoch 1/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 13s - loss: 1.1026 - accuracy: 0.0938
 6/30 [=====>........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2949 - accuracy: 0.0652 
30/30 [==============================] - 1s 33ms/step - loss: -5.4832 - accuracy: 0.0893 - val_loss: -49.9462 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 2/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: -52.2145 - accuracy: 0.0625
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -120.6972 - accuracy: 0.0961 - val_loss: -513.0211 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 3/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: -638.2873 - accuracy: 0.1250
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -968.3621 - accuracy: 0.1006 - val_loss: -2804.1062 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 4/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: -3427.3135 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -4571.7894 - accuracy: 0.0934 - val_loss: -10332.9727 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 5/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: -12963.2559 - accuracy: 0.0625
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -15268.3010 - accuracy: 0.0887 - val_loss: -29262.1191 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
Epoch 6/6

 1/30 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: -30990.6758 - accuracy: 0.1562
30/30 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: -40321.9540 - accuracy: 0.0960 - val_loss: -68548.6094 - val_accuracy: 0.1012
```

Any guidance is greatly appricated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a CNN you want the last layer to have as many nodes as the labels. So if you have 10 digits you want the last layer to have an output size 10. It usually has the activation function "softmax", which makes every value go to 0, except on value which is 1.

```
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus, this was very helpful!